# Rails: updating model triggers after_save callback "on: :create"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Rails 4.1.8.

So I have this thing:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_save :weak, on: :create

  def weak
    puts "lamerino"
  end
end
```

Right?

So I fire rails console:

```
2.1.4 :008 > post = Post.create(name: "slow")
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   SQL (0.1ms)  INSERT INTO "posts"....
lamerino

post.name = "slow-mo"
post.save

2.1.4 :014 > post.save
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   SQL (0.2ms)  UPDATE "posts" SET ...
lamerino
```

As you can see "lamerino" was printed twice. For create and for update operations. Now, I only want this to be printed only for `create` operations. I thought that passing in `on: :create` will do that thing, but apparently it does not.

I ended up using `after_create :weak`.

I would like to know why updating record triggered the `after_save :weak, on: :create` callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because only validation callbacks accept `on`

https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/12502